# mongoDB fine and replace on many documents

Tags: find-and-replace, mongodb

we have a collection and document with and an object called "status" we want to find all which have "status" = New or Contains New and replace with Complete

what is the correct syntax to FIND and REPLACE over 700k documents?

Comment: Do you have any reason not to want to use a normal update query?